# CSS / Less / Sass - Match every previous siblings when :hover

Tags: html, css, hover, less

In this code:

```
<div id="Container">
  <span class='first'>First</span>
  <span class='second'>Second</span>
  <span class='third'>Third</span>
</div>
```

I want to change color, when `:hover`.

1. IF (`.first:hover`) THEN `.first { color: red; }`
2. IF (`.second:hover`) THEN `.first, .second { color: red; }`
3. IF (`.third:hover`) THEN `.first, .second, .third { color: red; }`

Is this possible without JS? I can accept CSS Hacks :)

---

Possible answers:

1. @panther 's answer

---

More difficult version:

```
<div id="Container">
  <span class='first' style='color: red'>First</span>
  <span class='second' style='color: green'>Second</span>
  <span class='third' style='color: blue'>Third</span>
</div>
```

1. IF (`.first:hover`) THEN `.first { color: pink; }`
2. IF (`.second:hover`) THEN `.first, .second { color: pink; }`
3. IF (`.third:hover`) THEN `.first, .second, .third { color: pink; }`

---

Answers:

1. @Armfoot 's answer seems to be good :)

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible because Less still compiles into CSS and what you are looking for is not possible with CSS. (*Note:* I am not including any possible hacks when I say not possible with CSS)

Comment: @Harry never say never... maybe something can be done with the `@at-root` property, all having a common class as parent... I'm still thinking on this. +1 for the challenge :P

Comment: @Armfoot: Which is why I said, I am not including hacks.

Comment: @Harry [panther's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30592300/1326147) actually surprised me for its simplicity (despite not using the span classes). Haven't even thought in that way at all!

Comment: @Armfoot: it's a little trick, not clear solution. And it works just sometimes, for block elements with full width, or floated (without spaces between items). Sometimes it's possible to use it, in other cases JS is needed.

Comment: @Armfoot: Yes. However, I would still be careful in suggesting that as an answer because while it may work for the exact requirement specified in question, it may not if the question is a case of XY problem.

Comment: @123qwe: I've updated my answer with solution of your second question with different colors for `span`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way with [`@each` in SASS](http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive) based in [panther's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30592300/1326147):

```
$containerID: FirstSecondThird-Container;
##{$containerID}:hover span {color:pink} 
@each $spanclass, $spancolor in (first, red), (second, green), (third, blue) {
  ##{$containerID} span:hover ~ .#{$spanclass}, .#{$spanclass} {
    color: #{$spancolor};
  }
}
```

It's a little bit shorter but here's the result (generated CSS):

```css
#FirstSecondThird-Container:hover span {
  color: pink;
}
#FirstSecondThird-Container span:hover ~ .first, .first {
  color: red;
}
#FirstSecondThird-Container span:hover ~ .second, .second {
  color: green;
}
#FirstSecondThird-Container span:hover ~ .third, .third {
  color: blue;
}

span {display: block;} /* this line was not generated, it's just to place them vertically */
```

```html
<div id="FirstSecondThird-Container">
  <span class='first'>First</span>
  <span class='second'>Second</span>
  <span class='third'>Third</span>
</div>
```

Which has similar CSS rules to [panther's fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45zLdcvr/1/).

Nice challenge **123qwe** :)

Answer (score 7):

In CSS there is no previous sibling selector, but... you can sometimes do it using known selectors. Sometimes.

```
<style>
    span {color: #000; display: block;}
    div:hover span {color: #f00;}
    span:hover ~ span {color: #000}
</style>

<div id="FirstSecondThird-Container">
    <span class='first'>First</span>
    <span class='second'>Second</span>
    <span class='third'>Third</span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/45zLdcvr/

It works with `block` `span`s (of floated, of course). With `span`s has default `display: inline` it will blink when you will hover `div` in space between spans.

**UPDATE**:
You updated the question when each span has own color, then it could be:

```
span {color: red}
.second {color: green}
.third {color: blue}

span {display: block;}
div:hover span {color: pink;}
span:hover ~ .second {color: green}
span:hover ~ .third {color: blue}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/45zLdcvr/1/

Comment: I think, I can use `border : 1px solid transparent` for inline (-block/-flex) spans as the patch of blinking.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i think can do what you're looking to achieve neatly

```
@mixin color_on_hover($class){

@if $class==first {span:nth-of-type(1){color:red;}}
@else if $class==second {span:nth-of-type(1), span:nth-of-type(2){color:red;}}
@else if $class==third {span:nth-of-type(1), span:nth-of-type(2), span:nth-of-type(3){color:red;}}

}
span.first:hover{
@include color_on_hover(first);
}
span.second:hover{
@include color_on_hover(second);
}
span.third:hover{
@include color_on_hover(third);
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Sorry Django, this produces rules like `span.first:hover span.nth-of-type(1)` therefore it does not answer the question  (and you forgot the `c` in `include`). Think about it.

Comment: Yes it does, the level of customization is higher that way, try defining different colors for each action and you'll find yourself compelled to produce these rules.

Comment: [This fiddle has the generated CSS from your code](https://jsfiddle.net/45zLdcvr/2/) which does not provide a solution... Compare with [panther's fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45zLdcvr/1/) which is working...